# Jetpack Compose: how to save previous data using viewModel+composable

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-jetpack

I'm new to jetpack Compose. here is my question:
this is the backgroud: I have a Login process to go with two composables, each composalbe is a screen.  first screen is to let user input there email or phoneNumber. second screen is to let user input the validate Code.
this is my problem: I created two viewmodels for each compose. I input the phoneNumber, then navigate to the code page. when I close the code page, I found the data in first page is gone. I want to remain the data until my login process is finished.  how can I achieve that.
any help will be helpful. thanks.

I'm using `compose-destinations` to manage my routes

here's my sample:

```
loginPage.kt:

@Composable
fun LoginLayout(){
   val viewModel = remember { LoginPageData() }
   Column(){
      //here's the page contents
      Button(
      click ={
         // do the jump 
         navigaor.navigate(CodeInputPageDestioation())
      }
      )
   }

}
```

```
LoginPageData.kt

class LoginPageData : ViewModel(){
  //some properities
}
```

```
CodeInputPage.kt:

@Composable
fun CodeInputLayout(){
   val viewModel = remember { CodeInputData() }
   Column(){
      //here's the page contents
      Button(onclick = {
         navigator.popBackStack()
      }){

      }
   }

}
```

```
CodeInputData.kt

class CodeInputData : ViewModel(){
  //some properities
}
```

like the code above. When I navigate to CodeInputPage, then  click the button to call the `navigator.popBackStack()` my input in the LoginPage is gone. it seems like created a new LoginPageData().

Comment: You can make ```ViewModel``` instance in ```Activity``` and share its instance as parameter in ```Composable``` this is how you can manage single instance and value will be same for all the screens.

Comment: I have actually thought about this approach. However, in my scenario, I have only one activity, and the rest are composed of composable elements. If I were to place all ViewModel instances in the Activity, I would have to manage ViewModels myself, as it might lead to memory issues. Additionally, if all ViewModels are placed in the Activity, passing them as parameters to each other could become messy and cumbersome. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: This is my suggestion. Create only one screen that will contain login process. You can swap inputs based on state. Then define only one ViewModel that manages both things. Both are closely related, so in my opinion it's not a mistake.

Comment: thanks. I thought about this too. But I dont think it's the best way

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
**Persist data in data layer**

Long answer:
As Google suggest [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting#:%7E:text=You%20should%20hoist%20UI%20state%20to%20the%20lowest%20common%20ancestor):

> You should hoist UI state to the lowest common ancestor

Applying to your actual design this means you have to reach the data down to the data layer or domain layer if you have one. If i see this right you anyway need to send an e-mail with a verification code. This should be done by a lower layer. Later when the user  types in the code and press the verification button, the logic behind this button should be handled by your business logic. Here you need access to that verification code. I would save/persist all the data(email/phonenumber and verification code) in the data layer. Maybe a Room database is sufficient for you, maybe you want to store the data in firebase or anywhere else on the network or even both online and offline.

But you could also think on redesigning:

This means you could redesign to have only one screen with one viewmodel. Then the state would be kept in the screen.

You could redesign to have one viewmodel shared by two screens. Not sure if this is good practice. However then the state would be kept in viewmodel.